# How do I generate a heatmap of the world with by-state data?

Tags: linux, data-visualization, gis, heatmap

I have some dataset with pairs of the name of a state (not US state!) and a value (either categorical or on a scale). I would like to create a heatmap of the world, with the states marked on it, according to this data, on a Linux system.

Can I do this relatively easily with available desktop software, or is it something I need to write a program for (in which case I'll look into some scripting-based solution)?

PS - I know Excel has an add-on for this, but like I said - not on Windows.

Answer (score 1):

One way would be with an `R` script and `ggplot2` library.
Even if you have programming knowledge, R can be quite unique. You need to format your data in a long format and pass into ggplot as the example states below:

[image: ggplot2 geom_map]